# "In the market" or "on the market"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions, collocation, in-on

I am trying to help a friend of mine proofreading an English email and she has a preposition there that I am not completely certain is correct. The original sentence was this:

> [Name of the competitor] had the lowest price in the market -- [the price].

This seems a bit odd to me, but I can not be completely sure if I am right about the proper usage.

My intuition wants to say "on the market" at this point...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your intuition is correct. The sentence should be:

> {Name of the competitor} had the lowest price **on** the market...

Usage is idiomatic. "The market" isn't referring to a physical marketplace such as an open-air fish market, or a farmer's market. Instead, it is an abstraction, like an economic market, and may refer to automobiles or housing.

Usage is slightly different if the market is financial, such as a stock or commodities market.

- Buying and selling of stocks refers to "the stock market". A particular, but still abstract, instance is "the European stock market".
- A named market is a proper noun, often a physical entity, such as the Paris Bourse or the London Metals Exchange (LME). Virtual markets are markets too. The NASDAQ is an all-electronic exchange. Bitcoin is too.
- "Commodity" is used as an adjective to describe the type of market e.g. platinum options are traded **on** a commodities market such as the Chicago Mercantile Exchange (CME) or the LME.

Pork bellies are traded **on** an agricultural exchange (market). Pork belly futures are listed **by**, or **on**, the CME. The traders themselves are **in** the market to buy or sell pork bellies. That is metaphorical too. It doesn't describe location, but rather, intent to act. If the traders were **on** the market, then the traders themselves would be bought or sold! Very meta, to trade traders, and wrong, as traders aren't chattel.

#### Summary

One takes one's pigs **to** market, sells them **in** the marketplace, offers them as listed futures **on** a commodities exchange, and sells them to the highest bidder **on** the market.

Answer (score 20):

Generally speaking, only the commodity itself is *on* the market, while the traders themselves and other aspects of the trade are *in* the market. So one puts one’s pork bellies *on* the market at the lowest price *in* the market.

> **in the market**
>   : in the position of being a potential buyer <*in the market* for a house>
>   **on the market**
>   : available for purchase; also : up for sale <put their house *on the market*>[¹](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in+the+market)

Answer (score 0):

I am learning business English for LCCI exam from Oxford University Press books, which definitely use term 'in the market'. Examples: 
*'...company operates in the same market as you' 
'What market do you sell in?'
'Are you mainly in the European market?'*
This sounds strange, because being American-educated, I would use 'on' as a preposition in the sentences above.

Comment: All those sound perfectly normal to me as an American.

Comment: Making a conclusion from the said above:
"on" is used in American English; "in" is used in Brithsh English.
Am I right?

Comment: I assume you are commenting on bonbon ella's answer, but even if you are not, I would say no; "on" is used by sellers and "in" is used by buyers (as in MetaEd's answer) and there is no BrE/AmE split involved.